# How to make TypeScript Generic constraint apply to a function definition?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a following Preact/React component:

```
export interface ListItem {
  disabled?: boolean;
}


export interface MyCompProps<T extends ListItem> {
  value: T;
}


export function MyComp<T>(props: MyCompProps<T>) {

  const { value } = props;

  // ERROR - Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'T'.
  value.disabled;

  return (
    <div>
      {value.disabled ? 'True' : 'False'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since `T` satisfies constraints for `MyCompProps<T>`, shouldn't the `value` of type `T` include a field with name `disabled`? Also, if I modify the following code it works:

```
export function MyComp<T extends ListItem>(props: MyCompProps<T>) { return (/* ... */); }
```

But doing this defeats the point of declaring constraint at interface level?

Comment: because disabled is optional in ListItem, so T could even be empty in MyComp. That said,  TS has not enough knowledge to infer the actual typings.